# C++ char array to int and int to char array

Tags: c++

I've been trying to do this but I wasn't able to find any good source for it.

Basicly, I want to convert a char* variable (byte array) into an int and vis-versa.
Thanks.

Comment: The question is vague as you do not specify how the contents of the array should be processed.  There are at least three interpretations, including pointer casting, string conversion, and handling of byte array as 8-bit integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to convert a byte array into an int it is sufficient to use a reinterpret_cast.  Technically, this is UB, but if you know the bytes are in the right format, it usually results in exactly what you're asking for.

This is while noting the difference between a char* STRING and a char* BYTE ARRAY.

Answer (score 2):

To convert from string to integer you can use `atoi` function and `sprintf` to do it in other direction.

UPDATE (see comments):

Than you need to do following

```
char *word = "Hello world";
int ints[11];
for(int i=0; i<strlen(word); ++i)
        ints[i] = (int)word[i];
```

Comment: I was speaking of bitwise operators. Not string like convertions.

Comment: What do you mean?  Providing an example of what sort of data would be in the char*, and what sort of int you expect to end up with, would help.  "bitwise operators" in this case don't seem to make any sense, so the question must be unclear.

Comment: well, let's say I just read 4 bytes of a file. They're stored into char* and I'd like to make it an int. And I'd also like to turn an int into a char[4].  Not converting a number to a numerical string value.

Comment: but what do you mean stored in char* ? How do you read from file? you can use fscanf with a specified format string to read binary data from the file.

Comment: I would like to notice that `char` data type is actually an 1 byte integer value [0,255]. So you can cast char to int and back.